# Increase the red spell check line sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to increase the width/height/boldness of the spell check line presented when I mis-spell a word.

I would settle to edit pretty much any attribute as well, such as the color too, as it is not easily viewable in my theme (cobalt).

also posted [here](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/141709-/).